# Android : load(getClass().getClassLoader(),classLoadingStrategy) throws java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, byte-buddy

Im trying to create byteBuddy object under method proxy(...) in Android and then call on the byteBuddy object some methods:

```
<T> T proxy(Class<T> clz, InvocationHandler invocationHandler) {
    ByteBuddy byteBuddy = null;
    try {
        byteBuddy = new ByteBuddy(ClassFileVersion.JAVA_V6);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(byteBuddy!=null) {
        Class<?> enhanced = byteBuddy
                .subclass(clz, ConstructorStrategy.Default.IMITATE_SUPER_TYPE)
                .method(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(Object.class)))
                .intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(invocationHandler))
                .make().load(getClass().getClassLoader(), classLoadingStrategy)
                .getLoaded();

        ...
```

But on line with:

```
load(getClass().getClassLoader(), classLoadingStrategy)
```

ByteBuddy throws exception :

> 06-11 21:29:23.351  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load class
>   pdl.transport.overlay.fissione.FissioneTransport$FissioneHandler$ByteBuddy$vhLwLk79
>   06-11 21:29:23.351  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   net.bytebuddy.android.AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.load(AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.java:138)
>   06-11 21:29:23.351  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:3380)
>   06-11 21:29:23.351  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at pdl.transport.Messenger.proxy(Messenger.java:320)
>   06-11 21:29:23.351  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at pdl.transport.Messenger.async(Messenger.java:382)
>   06-11 21:29:23.351  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at pdl.transport.Messenger.async(Messenger.java:373)
>   06-11 21:29:23.351  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   pdl.transport.overlay.fissione.FissioneTransport.join(FissioneTransport.java:221)
>   06-11 21:29:23.351  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   pdl.transport.overlay.fissione.FissioneTransport.open(FissioneTransport.java:202)
>   06-11 21:29:23.351  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at pdl.transport.overlay.util.DHT.(DHT.java:37)
>   06-11 21:29:23.351  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at pdl.transport.overlay.util.DHT.main(DHT.java:117)
>   06-11 21:29:23.351  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.example.AndroidOverlay.MyActivity_newbie.onCreate(MyActivity_newbie.java:72)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289) 06-11
>   21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 06-11
>   21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 06-11
>   21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 06-11
>   21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 06-11 21:29:23.361 
>   12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 06-11 21:29:23.361 
>   12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195) 06-11
>   21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "pdl.transport.overlay.fissione.FissioneTransport$FissioneHandler$ByteBuddy$vhLwLk79"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/data/com.example.AndroidOverlay/app_TnUR5LUb/1Gzh1FCI.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] 06-11 21:29:23.361 
>   12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   net.bytebuddy.android.AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.load(AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.java:136)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ ... 22 more 06-11 21:29:23.361 
>   12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ Suppressed:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex file
>   '/data/data/com.example.AndroidOverlay/app_TnUR5LUb/1Gzh1FCI.jar' from
>   memory: Unrecognized version number in
>   /data/data/com.example.AndroidOverlay/app_TnUR5LUb/1Gzh1FCI.jar: 0 3 6
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native
>   Method) 06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:295)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:111) 06-11
>   21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   dalvik.system.DexFile.loadDex(DexFile.java:151) 06-11 21:29:23.361 
>   12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:265) 06-11
>   21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:231) 06-11
>   21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:109) 06-11
>   21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
>   06-11 21:29:23.361  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.(DexClassLoader.java:57) 06-11
>   21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   net.bytebuddy.android.AndroidClassLoadingStrategy$DexProcessor$ForSdkCompiler.makeClassLoader(AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.java:257)
>   06-11 21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at
>   net.bytebuddy.android.AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.load(AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.java:132)
>   06-11 21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ ... 22 more 06-11 21:29:23.371 
>   12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg
>   -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=div --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --dex-file=/data/data/com.example.AndroidOverlay/app_TnUR5LUb/1Gzh1FCI.jar
>   --oat-fd=64 --art-fd=-1 --oat-location=/data/data/com.example.AndroidOverlay/app_TnUR5LUb/1Gzh1FCI.dex
>   --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m) because non-0 exit status 06-11 21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ ... 33 more 06-11 21:29:23.371 
>   12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to find dex file
>   '/data/data/com.example.AndroidOverlay/app_TnUR5LUb/1Gzh1FCI.jar' in
>   oat location
>   '/data/data/com.example.AndroidOverlay/app_TnUR5LUb/1Gzh1FCI.dex':
>   Failed to find existing oat file at
>   /data/data/com.example.AndroidOverlay/app_TnUR5LUb/1Gzh1FCI.dex: File
>   size of 0 bytes not large enough to contain ELF header of 52 bytes:
>   '/data/data/com.example.AndroidOverlay/app_TnUR5LUb/1Gzh1FCI.dex'
>   06-11 21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ ... 33 more 06-11 21:29:23.371 
>   12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ Suppressed:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "pdl.transport.overlay.fissione.FissioneTransport$FissioneHandler$ByteBuddy$vhLwLk79"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.AndroidOverlay-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]] 06-11 21:29:23.371 
>   12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   06-11 21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>   06-11 21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>   06-11 21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ ... 24 more 06-11 21:29:23.371 
>   12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ Suppressed:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   pdl.transport.overlay.fissione.FissioneTransport$FissioneHandler$ByteBuddy$vhLwLk79
>   06-11 21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 06-11
>   21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781) 06-11
>   21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841) 06-11
>   21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504) 06-11
>   21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay W/System.err﹕ ...
>   25 more 06-11 21:29:23.371  12028-12028/com.example.AndroidOverlay
>   W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not
>   found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Im using dx-1.7.jar from http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/tools/dx/1.7/dx-1.7.jar
and byte-buddy-0.6.8.jar,byte-buddy-android-0.6.8.jar

Am I missing something? I get also Could not run Dynamic type.(Failed resolution of:  Lorg/objectweb/asmType;) on yours android example application, it seems like Im missing something, some library or I dont know...
Thank you for answers.

**EDIT1:**
Im using Lollipop and this is how I setup AndroidClassLoadingStrategy:

```
final File dir = this.getDir("dexgen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Messenger.setClassLoadingStrategy(new AndroidClassLoadingStrategy(dir));
```

which sets to class Messenger where I have method proxy(...)

```
public static void setClassLoadingStrategy(ClassLoadingStrategy cls) {
    classLoadingStrategy = cls;
}
```

and classLoadingStrategy is defined as

```
private static ClassLoadingStrategy classLoadingStrategy;
```

**Edit 2:**
After All I took ByteBuddy example application, tried lines for Android lollipop replacing

```
File file = TestActivity.this.getDir(RandomString.make(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

for one of theese which should be replacement, tried them all and all gives same exception, just from different class-activity

```
File file = getCodeCacheDir(); //NOT WORKING
// File file = getApplicationContext().getCodeCacheDir(); //NOT WORKING
// File file = getBaseContext().getCodeCacheDir(); //NOT WORKING
// File file = TestActivity.this.getCodeCacheDir(); //NOT WORKING
```

Exception still:

```
06-12 23:18:57.916    1947-1947/net.bytebuddy.android.test W/net.bytebuddy﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load class net.bytebuddy.renamed.java.lang.Object$ByteBuddy$uSYJ5787$auxiliary$MBywjCuh
```

I created and putted on my website sources for future possibility to reproduce error here:

[bashism.com/shared/ByteBuddyTest.tar.gz](http://bashism.com/shared/ByteBuddyTest.tar.gz)

**Edit 3:**

Android version: 5.0.1 Lollipop

Device: Samsung galaxy S4

IDE: IntelliJ Idea 14.1.3

**Edit 4:**
After changing inside Main Activity:

```
File file = TestActivity.this.getDir(RandomString.make(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and inside net.bytebuddy.android.AndroidClassLoadingStrategy

```
public ForSdkCompiler(DexOptions dexFileOptions, CfOptions dexCompilerOptions) {
dexFileOptions.targetApiLevel = 13;
this.dexFileOptions = dexFileOptions;
this.dexCompilerOptions = dexCompilerOptions;
```

}

Seems working/stable, further debugging soon

Comment: What Android version are you using? And what class loading strategy are you using? It must be the `AndroidClassLoadingStrategy`. How do you set it up? You need to use an internal folder such as in the example app, otherwise Android's security manager kicks in.

Comment: I just added Edit with more informations, thank you

Comment: Seems like you need to use `File dir = context.getCodeCacheDir()` for storing dex files on Lollipop. (http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) for storing files. The Android people tend to change their security settings and API, unfortunately.

Comment: Hello, Im sorry, but Im unable to find method getCodeCacheDir under applicationContext or Activity, how do you call it from activity? Thank you and sorry for trouble...
Ah, I see, I had target setted to different, so I was unable to call it

Comment: You need to compile against API version 21 which is Lollipop. This version added the `getCodeCacheDir` method on the `ContextWrapper` subclass which `Activity` implements.

Comment: Ive tried
`final File dir = getApplicationContext().getCodeCacheDir();//this.getCode getCodeCacheDir();
  Messenger.setClassLoadingStrategy(new AndroidClassLoadingStrategy(dir));`
and
`final File dir = this.getCodeCacheDir();//this.getCode getCodeCacheDir();
  Messenger.setClassLoadingStrategy(new AndroidClassLoadingStrategy(dir));`

under activity without success, still getting same exception :/

Comment: Just to be sure: Can you run the example app that lies on GitHub? Can your collegue run your app that crashes? From the exception, it seems like the created class cannot be found. Maybe use `Activity.class.getClassLoader()`? Could you create a minimal example of your failing app that I can test? I use Lollipop myself.

Comment: Yep, I will make some test app and host it, but I think probably in several hours, Im just leaving, I really appreciate it, my project just lays on this already 4th day. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for late response, I had messed day today, so I just updated main thread and added link to sources, Im using IntelliJ Idea in case you would like to use same environment, Im not sure with library dx-1.7.jar, Ive tried with or without, still giving same error. Thank you

Comment: So I added the link with project in main thread, is it working for you?

Comment: Looking at it this evening.

Comment: The file contains the Byte Buddy sample project which works for me.

Comment: On Android Lollipop 5.0.1, with usage of `File file = getCodeCacheDir();` ? Just not working for me on this version of android, its not default Byte Buddy sample, its changed there the way of getting cacheDir

Comment: I saw this, I mean, there is no difference, apart from this. You example works on my device. I willt try to investigate this further.

Comment: The actual error here is that the embedded classes.dex file within the generated <rand>.jar is of version 036, but the dex2oat tool expects it to have a version of 035 (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/lollipop-release/runtime/dex_file.cc) (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html). I have confirmed this behavior on stock android 5.1.1 on a nexus 6 (patching classes.dex to have 035 in the header results in dex2oat being able to generate an oat [no idea if it works]). chances are different devices generate different versioned classes.dex files.

Comment: A new version that fixed this problem is now released.

Answer (score 2):

As I alluded to in my above comment, the issue is that the DEX file generated is currently too new (the newer version apparently introduces "extended opcodes") for the underlying ART machinery to handle. The actual issue likely stems from different devices having different default `DexOptions.targetApiLevel` values (that likely ignore actual API build targets). To fix this, any class loading strategy involving `classes.dex` files should specifically set this value to `13` or lower to ensure that the proper dex files are generated. For example, in @raphw's [`AndroidClassLoadingStrategy`](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-android/src/main/java/net/bytebuddy/android/AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.java), the `DexProcessor.ForSdkCompiler` constructor could be modified to specifically set this value e.g.:

```java
public ForSdkCompiler(DexOptions dexFileOptions, CfOptions dexCompilerOptions) {
    dexFileOptions.targetApiLevel = 13;
    this.dexFileOptions = dexFileOptions;
    this.dexCompilerOptions = dexCompilerOptions;
}
```

Comment: Hello, so I tried yours fix and on bytebuddy exampe it seems working and stable, I will mark answer useful later when I will do some more debugging and research. Thank you

Comment: I got recently hold of a new phone and I could finally verify the reported error. Also, I can confirm that your solution works. I am releasing a new version of Byte Buddy tomorrow where your fix is adapted. Thank you for researching this!